# How to call static view helper method in controller?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller

like in topic, I have two static method in view helper but when I try to call in controller action by

```
Zend_View_Helper_SomeHelper::firstStaticMethod();
```

I got error:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/View/Helper/SomeHelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /library/Zend/Loader.php on line 134 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/View/Helper/SomeHelper.php' for inclusion (include_path='/application/../library:/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /library/Zend/Loader.php on line 134 Fatal error: Class 'Zend_View_Helper_SomeHelper' not found in /application/modules/default/controllers/Controller.php on line 174
```

Helper code:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_SomeHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    //....//
    public static function firstStaticMethod(){
        //some code hear
    }
    public static function secoundStaticMethod(){
        //some code hear
    }
}
```

I need to use this method in helpers and action.
any ideas?

Comment: Where on the file system is your helper located?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really use the Zend namespace for user-land code.

Comment: @TimFountain - in /application/modules/default/views/helpers/

Comment: @TimFountain hmm yes you have right better way is use my own namespace. Thanks for help.

Comment: @TimFountain I do it just like you said but still doesn't work. I have an error: Fatal error: Class 'My_View_Helper_SomeHelper' not found in ../application/modules/default/controllers/TestController.php on line 174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$viewHelperObj = $this->view->getHelper('SomeHelper');
$viewHelperObj->secoundStaticMethod();
```